# PowerShell: Exchange Management Shell: Unable to execute the variable to modify the multivalued variable EmailAddresses

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-management-shell

```
Function Get-GmailAlias ($ID) {
    $a = (Get-RemoteMailbox $ID |
             Select-Object DisplayName,PrimarySmtpAddress, @{ Name="EmailAddresses"; Expression={$_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object { $_.PrefixString -ceq "smtp" } | ForEach-Object { $_.SmtpAddress }}}).EmailAddresses |
             Where-Object { $_ -like '*gmail*' } 

    $b=@()
    foreach ($mem in $a) {
        $b += "'$mem'"
    }
    $c= $b -join ', '
    return $c
}
```

When you call the function with a UPN the result would be as follows:

```
'kiran.kumar@gmail.com', 'kiran_kumar@gmail.com'
```

I'm trying to call the function in below cmdlet.

```
Set-RemoteMailbox kpv@gmail.com -EmailAddresses @{Remove=Get-GmailAlias('kpv@gmail.com')}
```

I get the following output:

```
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/Kiran Kumar' have been modified.
```

I tried below methods:

```
>@{Remove=$(Get-GmailAlias('kpv@gmail.com'))} # Alternative-1
>$c = Get-GmailAlias('kpv@gmail.com')
@{Remove="$c"} # Alternative-2
>$c = "@{Remove = $(Get-GmailAlias('kpv@gmail.com'))}"
Set-RemoteMailbox kpv@gmail.com -EmailAddresses $c # Alternative-3
```

None of the above worked and also alternative-3 gave me below error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'EmailAddresses'. Cannot convert value "@{Remove = 'kiran.kumar@gmail.com', 'kiran_kumar@gmail.com'}" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection".
```

Kindly assist me find out why I'm unable to execute the variable/function in -EmailAddresses.

Comment: `Set-RemoteMailbox kpv@gmail.com -EmailAddresses @{Remove="kiran.kumar@gmail.com","kiran_kumar@gmail.com"}` - do you get the same error for this?

Comment: @gms0ulman It works; I could use a looping technique to remove the smtps I want but I wanna know why I'm unable to execute the variable in the cmdlet.

Comment: Any luck if you use double quotes and delimit using <comma> instead of <comma><space>? `"'$mem'"` -> `"""$mem"""`  and `$c= $b -join ', '` -> `$c= $b -join ','`. No access to Exchange server to test.